# Efficient way to edit index ranges in subsetting calls

Tags: r, regex, subset

The everpresent problem of porting code from a language whose indices start with zero to a language whose indices start with one, again...
In this case I want to port a long block that goes like

```
x[0:3] =  c(65,43, 22)
x[4:7] = c(23, 17,93, 7)
```

and so on for dozens of lines.  I'm reasonably comfortable with regex, so I can generate a pattern
that searches for , e.g.  "\[[0:9]{1,}:" and so on, but I'd hate to have to then extract each numeric sequence, convert to numeric, add one, and then `paste0` it all back together.
Is there a better approach, and for that matter, is there an existing `R` package that can automagically "shift" all the indices in text strings?

Followup: yeah I could dump this file into the source language, create `x` , print `x` values, and feed that to `R`, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to translate the indexes at run time? Or you have a script as text input that you want to transform? Is the entirety of the text file "parse-able" R code? Do you have indexing that looks like `x[5]` or `x[c(4, 7)]` or any other format?

Comment: @MrFlick  I just want to  automate editing a source file.  This would only happen once as I port the source code.   The actual source is like  `x[0..3] = {65,34,22}` but it's trivial to replace the `..` with `:`and convert `{ }` to `c( )` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much later, it occurs to me that, instead of trying to replace numerals, modifying the index definitions is much easier.

Example:

```
frist <- '[0:3]'
secnod <- gsub('[[]','[1+(', frist) 
finlaly <- gsub('[]]',')]',secnod)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input really looks like this

```
input <- "x[0..3] = {65, 34, 22}
x[4..7] = {23, 17, 93, 7}"
```

Then you can use `str_replace_all` to help with the transformation. For example

```
library(stringr)
output <- str_replace_all(input, pattern=r"((\w+\[)(\d+)\.\.(\d+)\])", replacement=function(x) {
  m <- str_match(x, r"((\w+\[)(\d+)\.\.(\d+)\])")
  paste0(m[,2], as.numeric(m[,3])+1, ":", as.numeric(m[,4])+1, "]")
})
output <- str_replace_all(output, pattern=r"((\{)([^\}]+)(\}))", replacement="c(\\2)")
cat(output)
# x[1:4] = c(65, 34, 22)
# x[5:8] = c(23, 17, 93, 7)
```

This uses a transformation function to increment the values of the indexes in the match.

Comment: Thanks for working out those regexes!  Guess there isn't really an alternative method.